# Java code skipping ahead to next method while in the middle of current method

Tags: java, swing

I asked this question earlier but I thought I had solved it so I answered it. I was wrong. I am having serious problems with my GUI. I am attempting to implement this double list inside of a very large program for work. In an attempt to figure it out I have isolated the task into a smaller Java program. I want to utilize a double list in my program that allows a user to pick and choose from a list of items and move them to a second list. That list will later be manipulated. The problem I am having in my bigger program is that I have two GUI's. The first is the double list and the second is a JOptionsPane method that will cycle through all of the items selected and allow the user to make changes to each. The problem is that when the program gets to the double list it also displays the JOptionsPane which obviously is a problem. I have tried using System.exit as well as a "if" statement so the next method won't run until the confirm button in the double list has been clicked but this does not work.

Can someone please take a look and help me? I've been on this problem for two days and am becoming very frustrated.

The output:
1. Without the if statement the GUI method and whatever method comes after it will run at the same time.
2. With the if statement the next method won't run at all. (And in the case of my main program where I have a while statement an endless loop will occur.

ListExample_UltraExtended

```
package mathtesting;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ListExample_UltraExtended implements  ActionListener{

    JList itemList, shoppingList;
    JButton buttonin, buttonout, buttonConfirm;
    static int confirm=0;

    // The ListModels we will be using in the example.
    DefaultListModel shopping, items;

    public JPanel createContentPane (){

        // Create the final Panel.
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();

        // Instantiate the List Models.
        shopping = new DefaultListModel();
        items = new DefaultListModel();

        // Things to be in the list.


        String[] shoppingItems = new String[ArrayClass.importList.size()];
        shoppingItems = ArrayClass.importList.toArray(shoppingItems);

        System.out.println(shoppingItems);

        // Using a for loop, we add every item in the String array
        // into the ListModel.

        for(int i = 0; i < shoppingItems.length; i++)
        {
            shopping.addElement(shoppingItems[i]);
        }

        // Creation of the list.
        // We set the cells in the list to be 20px x 140px.

        itemList = new JList(shopping);
        itemList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        itemList.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        itemList.setFixedCellWidth(140);
        itemList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        // We then add them to a JScrollPane.
        // This means when we remove items from the JList
        // it will not shrink in size.
        JScrollPane list1 = new JScrollPane(itemList);

        shoppingList = new JList(items);
        shoppingList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        shoppingList.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        shoppingList.setFixedCellWidth(140);
        shoppingList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        // We add this list to a JScrollPane too.
        // This is so the list is displayed even though there are 
        // currently no items in the list.
        // Without the scrollpane, the list would not show.
        JScrollPane list2 = new JScrollPane(shoppingList);

        // We create the buttons to be placed between the lists.
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonin = new JButton(">>");
        buttonin.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonin);

        buttonConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        buttonConfirm.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonConfirm);

        buttonout = new JButton("<<");
        buttonout.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonout);

        // This final bit of code uses a BoxLayout to space out the widgets
        // in the GUI.

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(list1);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        bottomPanel.add(list2);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));

        totalGUI.add(bottomPanel);
        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGUI;
    }

    // In this method, we create a square JPanel of a colour and set size
    // specified by the arguments.

    private JPanel createSquareJPanel(Color color, int size) {
        JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel();
        tempPanel.setBackground(color);
        tempPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        tempPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        tempPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        return tempPanel;
    }

    // valueChanged is the method that deals with a ListSelectionEvent.
    // This simply changes the boxes that are selected to true.

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        int i = 0;

        // When the 'in' button is pressed,
        // we take the indices and values of the selected items
        // and output them to an array.

        if(e.getSource() == buttonin)
        {
            int[] fromindex = itemList.getSelectedIndices();
            Object[] from = itemList.getSelectedValues();

            // Then, for each item in the array, we add them to
            // the other list.
            for(i = 0; i < from.length; i++)
            {
                items.addElement(from[i]);
                System.out.println(items);
            }

            // Finally, we remove the items from the first list.
            // We must remove from the bottom, otherwise we try to 
            // remove the wrong objects.
            for(i = (fromindex.length-1); i >=0; i--)
            {
                shopping.remove(fromindex[i]);
            }
        }

        // If the out button is pressed, we take the indices and values of
        // the selected items and output them to an array.
        else if(e.getSource() == buttonout)
        {
            Object[] to = shoppingList.getSelectedValues();
            int[] toindex = shoppingList.getSelectedIndices();

            // Then, for each item in the array, we add them to
            // the other list.
            for(i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
            {
                shopping.addElement(to[i]);
            }

            // Finally, we remove the items from the first list.
            // We must remove from the bottom, otherwise we try to
            // remove the wrong objects.
            for(i = (toindex.length-1); i >=0; i--)
            {
                items.remove(toindex[i]);
                System.out.println(items);
            }

        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonConfirm)
        {
            System.out.println("confirmed");
            confirm++;
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JListExample - Adding and Removing [=]");

        ListExample_UltraExtended demo = new ListExample_UltraExtended();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ArrayClass (basically my main class)

```
package mathtesting;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ArrayClass 

{

    public static ArrayList<String> importList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String args[]){

        importList.add("1");
        importList.add("2");
        importList.add("3");



        final ListExample_UltraExtended example = new ListExample_UltraExtended();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListExample_UltraExtended.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

        if(ListExample_UltraExtended.confirm>0){
        NextStage next = new NextStage();

        next.test();
        }

    }



}
```

NextStage (This is the class I'm testing with, I want it to appear only after the entire ListExample GUI has run and the user has clicked confirm).

```
package mathtesting;

public class NextStage 

{

    public void test(){

        System.out.println("The next class has been called");

    }

}
```

For those who prefer to skim here are some snipplets:

Here is where I try to use the confirm button:

```
 }else if(e.getSource() == buttonConfirm)
        {
            System.out.println("confirmed");
            confirm++;
            System.exit(0);

        }
```

Here is where I call the first GUI, then use an if statement to make sure that the button has been clicked before the rest runs:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListExample_UltraExtended.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

        if(ListExample_UltraExtended.confirm>0){
        NextStage next = new NextStage();

        next.test();
        }
```

Comment: Please don't ask new questions that are exactly the same problem. Instead just edit your previous question with the information you have learned so we are more able to help you. Posting 2 questions makes difficult to track the progress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BufferedWriter double quotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504447/bufferedwriter-double-quotations)

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also as @poolie said, post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please). We don't need code snippets or your full code, but reduce your code to a minimal example which we can copy-paste and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did play around with your code and from my understanding the following code

```
if(ListExample_UltraExtended.confirm>0){
    NextStage next = new NextStage();
    next.test();
}
```

Runs after you start your program, as soon as the void run() method is called, the flow of execution reach the above code and check the condition. Obviously the value of confirm is zero because you have not yet clicked anything yet.

I think your expectation form the above line of code is to not get executed until you set the value of confirm in your e.getSource() function. Well, unfortunately that is not how it works.

I have a solution for you and I am not sure if that meets your requirement but, it does what you want and that is to trigger the test method of next as soon as confirm button is clicked.

Add a new method to your **ArrayClass** as follow:

```
public static void invokeNextStage() {
   NextStage next = new NextStage();
   next.test();
}
```

And then go to your other class **ListExample_UltraExtended** and put a call to the invokeNextStage method of ArrayClass where you are incrementing the value of confirm, as shown below:

```
else if(e.getSource() == buttonConfirm){
  System.out.println("confirmed");
  //not needed anymore
  confirm++;

  //invokes the next stage test method 
  ArrayClass.invokeNextStage();     
  System.exit(0);    
}
```

What happens above is, as soon as you click the confirm button ArrayClass.invokeNextStage method is called and inside that you have your next stage code that you wish to do your work.

Output below:

> [2]
>
> [2, 3]
>
> confirmed
>
> The next class has been called

Comment: Thank you very much! That solution worked perfectly. I will have to change how it's implemented in my actual program but I understand what you did and I can use that to fix my problem. Thanks again very much, my two day headache is relieved.

Comment: You are welcome. It was harder for me to understand what you asked in your question than to come up with the fix :P